# Google cloud datastore create Entity with parent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

when using library  `com.google.appengine.api.datastore` I used to create the entity with parent key this way

```
Entity incEntity = new Entity(PERSON_KIND, parentKey);
this.datastore.put(incEntity);
```

now I'm using `com.google.cloud.datastore` library and I am trying to find how to create an entity with parent key, but can't find any tutorial how to do it? I thought of something like this, but can you confirm this is the correct way to do it?

```
FullEntity<IncompleteKey> newPerson = com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity.newBuilder()
                                                                                   ...
                                                                                   .set("parent",
                                                                                        parentKey) // TODO not sure!!!
                                                                                   .build();
```

Comment: [See the examples here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-key-with-parent-java) to create a key with parents. Then, use that key to [create the entity like in the example here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#creating_an_entity). Hope that helps!

Comment: oh but of course, I kinda overlooked it , looking at the former way of creating entity with parent key.. my bad. thank you